# scp many files without reentering password, all different paths

Tags: ssh, command-line, scp

How can I achieve the result of many of

```
scp ~/here/is/one me@remote:~/where/it/goes
scp ~/yet/another me@remote:~/the/second/place
scp ~/the/number/three/one me@remote:~/foo/bar/qux
```

with only entering the password for that remote user once?

Comment: Please consider setting up SSH keys. Allowing passwords for SSH authentication is bad for security, and attackers are actively probing systems for it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With OpenSSH you can use its "master mode", whereby you first run an `ssh` which will establish the connection, authenticate, and then place itself in the background while keeping its connection alive waiting for further instructions to perform. Such background connection will be represented by a *named UNIX socket* which is purposefully created by the self-backgrounded `ssh` process. You therefore direct your `scp` commands to use such background connection instead of establishing their own new ones, until you finally close it explicitly.

For instance, in the example below the background connection is used through a UNIX socket on file arbitrarily named `bgconn` in the current directory:

```sh
ssh -fMNS bgconn -o ControlPersist=yes me@remote
scp -o ControlPath=bgconn ~/here/is/one me@remote:~/where/it/goes
scp -o ControlPath=bgconn ~/yet/another me@remote:~/the/second/place
scp -o ControlPath=bgconn ~/the/number/three/one me@remote:~/foo/bar/qux
ssh -S bgconn -O exit -
```

The first `ssh` establishes the connection while the last one simply instructs the first one to terminate it and exit, which will also remove the `bgconn` socket file. The commands in between are directed to use the named UNIX socket, hence the already established connection, to copy their files. Note that you can run as many `scp` (and `ssh` and `sftp` too) commands as you wish, all utilizing the same background connection, provided that you direct them to use the named socket like in the example above.

Options used in the first `ssh` in particular:

- `-f` places `ssh` to background after authentication succeeds
- `-M` enables master mode
- `-N` do not request any remote command, or else it would execute a (pointless in this case) remote shell as per default behavior
- `-S` path to a name for the UNIX socket that will be created on file-system
- `-o ControlPersist=yes` make the backgrounded `ssh` process persist until explicitly closed, or else it would exit on its own accord at the end of the first operation

---

How OpenSSH "master mode" works under the hood:

The SSH protocol natively allows several [so-called "channels"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-5) to share one single SSH connection. Each such channel represents one service among those supported by SSH, e.g. a terminal session, a remote command, a port-forwarding, and so on. This is essentially the basis on top of which it is possible to request for instance a port-forwarding *together with* the typical terminal session.

The `ssh` client command by OpenSSH courteously exports this connection-sharing facility to external applications as well, by means of its "master mode" as described above. See an [official description here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.mux).

Comment: A few words of technical explanation (or pointers to such) would be nice.

Comment: @U.Windl Sure, I can try to, if it's not too deep down the SSH protocol's details.  Which aspects would you like insights about?

Comment: Specifically what the first command does in order to be used by the subsequent commands. And how the last command will undo what the first command did...

Comment: @U.Windl see edit

Comment: @LL3 Thanks, I edited it, hoping I did not mess it up. Possibly the part at the end could be trimmed a bit now.

Answer (score 10):

With the SSH suite, if you want to avoid typing password multiple times, you should use ssh keys.

They are generated by `ssh-keygen`, can be sent to the other host with `ssh-copy-id` (only the public key is sent).

If the key is not cyphered, no password is asked.

If you don’t trust the private status of your file (attack…), you can have the key cyphered `ssh-keygen -p`.

With cyphered keys, the password is asked, but you can start `eval $(ssh-agent)`. This agent can store in memory the key when you type `ssh-add`. Then the password is only asked once by `ssh-add` and the key is available for ssh/scp.

When you don’t need the agent anymore, `ssh-agent -k`.